# Explaining why (7.8/39) = .2 does not return results in a where clause

Tags: sql, vertica

So I know why (7.8/39)=.2 does not return results in a where clause in SQL while ROUND((7.8/39),1)=.2 will return results, but I don't know how to explain it clearly to someone I work with and I would like to provide them something to read other then me telling them that that will not work as part of their where clause.

Thanks you,

Jalal

Comment: What does `select 7.8/32` return?

Comment: Returns .2 visually but for his code to work I had him round use WHERE ROUND((X/Y),1)=.2                   X/Y=.2 does not return results if used in the where clause even though both return .2 in a select statement.

Comment: Sorry... I put 32 instead of 39, edited the main post. My brain is frazzled its been a long week.

Comment: [Q: Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/62576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).  This can be hard to explain, if you don't just "get" it.

Where do I start?  Integers are pretty easy to represent in the bits that a CPU understands.  So, 00000101 is interpreted as 5 -- and exactly 5 -- because it is 2^2 + 2^0.

However, this doesn't work for fractional parts of numbers. To solve this, computer scientists invented two forms of numbers.  One is what I personally think of as BCD (binary coded decimal) but databases call `decimal` or `numeric`.  Each digit is represent as a number.  You only need 4 bits for a digit, so this looks like:

```
0011    0001    1111     0000     1001
   3       1       .        0        9
```

This exactly represents 31.09.  Just keep adding bits.  Note:  This is conceptual.  Exact implementation may vary.

The second method is exponential notation.  That is:  xxx * 2^ yyy, where xxx and yyy are integers.  For example, 0.25 is 1 * 2^(-2).  The "1" and "-2" can be exactly represented.

This works well for *approximations* of numbers.  The problem is that 0.25 can be exactly represented.  But 0.24 and 0.26 cannot be.  They end up with some complicated numbers being involved.  The same is true of 0.2 -- which is the number you are trying to represent.

What happens is that you write 0.2 and it is represented as 0.00110011001 (say).  But when you do the calculation it ends up being 0.00110011000.  Oooh.  That last bit changed, so it is really more like 0.19997 (well, a bit more '9's in practice).  The values are not exactly equal.

The moral:  don't use equality on floating point numbers.  The numbers may look the same but differ in some piddling binary decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my "Vertica Analytic Database v9.3.1-0" as my `SELECT VERSION()` returns:

`select  (7.8/39)=.2  as is_it_true`

returns:

`is_it_true`

`true`

To be sure and avoid any floating-point issues, try casting the two equality operands to the same type:

`select  (7.8/39)::NUMERIC(5,1) = .2::NUMERIC(5,1)`